# How to get `skbio` PCoA (Principal Coordinate Analysis) results?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra, scikits, dimensionality-reduction, skbio

I'm looking at the `attributes` of `skbio's` `PCoA` method (listed below).  I am new to this `API` and I want to be able to get the `eigenvectors` and the original points projected onto the new axis similar to `.fit_transform` in `sklearn.decomposition.PCA` so I can create some `PC_1 vs PC_2`-style plots. I figured out how to get the `eigvals` and `proportion_explained` but `features` comes back as `None`.

Is that because it's in beta?

If there are any tutorials that use this, that would be greatly appreciated.  I am a huge fan of `scikit-learn` and would like to start using more of `scikit's` products.

```
|  Attributes
 |  ----------
 |  short_method_name : str
 |      Abbreviated ordination method name.
 |  long_method_name : str
 |      Ordination method name.
 |  eigvals : pd.Series
 |      The resulting eigenvalues.  The index corresponds to the ordination
 |      axis labels
 |  samples : pd.DataFrame
 |      The position of the samples in the ordination space, row-indexed by the
 |      sample id.
 |  features : pd.DataFrame
 |      The position of the features in the ordination space, row-indexed by
 |      the feature id.
 |  biplot_scores : pd.DataFrame
 |      Correlation coefficients of the samples with respect to the features.
 |  sample_constraints : pd.DataFrame
 |      Site constraints (linear combinations of constraining variables):
 |      coordinates of the sites in the space of the explanatory variables X.
 |      These are the fitted site scores
 |  proportion_explained : pd.Series
 |      Proportion explained by each of the dimensions in the ordination space.
 |      The index corresponds to the ordination axis labels
```

Here is my code to generate the `principal component analysis` object.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn import decomposition
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_style("whitegrid", {'axes.grid' : False})
import skbio
from scipy.spatial import distance

%matplotlib inline
np.random.seed(0)

# Iris dataset
DF_data = pd.DataFrame(load_iris().data, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])],
                       columns = load_iris().feature_names)
n,m = DF_data.shape
# print(n,m)
# 150 4

Se_targets = pd.Series(load_iris().target, 
                       index = ["iris_%d" % i for i in range(load_iris().data.shape[0])], 
                       name = "Species")

# Scaling mean = 0, var = 1
DF_standard = pd.DataFrame(StandardScaler().fit_transform(DF_data), 
                           index = DF_data.index,
                           columns = DF_data.columns)

# Distance Matrix
Ar_dist = distance.squareform(distance.pdist(DF_standard.T, metric="braycurtis")) # (m x m) distance measure
DM_dist = skbio.stats.distance.DistanceMatrix(Ar_dist, ids=DF_standard.columns)
PCoA = skbio.stats.ordination.pcoa(DM_dist)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the transformed sample coordinates with `OrdinationResults.samples`. This will return a `pandas.DataFrame` row-indexed by sample ID (i.e. the IDs in your distance matrix). Since principal coordinate analysis operates on a distance matrix of samples, transformed feature coordinates (`OrdinationResults.features`) are not available. Other ordination methods in scikit-bio accepting a sample x feature table as input will have the transformed feature coordinates available (e.g. CA, CCA, RDA).

Side note: the `distance.squareform` call is unnecessary because `skbio.DistanceMatrix` supports square- or vector-form arrays.

Comment: I believe `.samples` returned nothing.  I can try again and I'll make sure I have my  `skbio` updated.  I've been reading about PCoA and a lot of the resources are rather cryptic.  In terms of PCA, is it the same steps but eigendecomposition on the distance matrix instead of the covariance matrix?

Comment: `.samples` is required for an `OrdinationResults` produced by `pcoa`. If you're still getting `None` can you please post an issue on the [scikit-bio issue tracker](https://github.com/biocore/scikit-bio/issues)? My understanding is that PCoA is applied to a distance matrix, allowing use of non-Euclidean distance metrics, whereas PCA is applied to a feature table and uses Euclidean distance. Thus, running PCoA on a Euclidean distance matrix is equivalent to PCA. [Here's](http://ordination.okstate.edu/overview.htm#Principal_coordinates_analysis) a useful resource for ordination methods.

Comment: `DF = skbio.OrdinationResults(long_method_name="TESTING",short_method_name="test",eigvals=PCoA.eigvals, samples=DF_data)
DF.samples`  gives me back my original data that hasn't been transformed.   Am I doing this incorrectly?

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't need to construct an `skbio.OrdinationResults` object directly, it just holds the results of an ordination method. Each ordination method in scikit-bio creates this results object for you, which you can access the results from. Use the [`skbio.stats.ordination.pcoa`](http://scikit-bio.org/docs/latest/generated/generated/skbio.stats.ordination.pcoa.html) function to run PCoA on an `skbio.DistanceMatrix` object. You will receive an `skbio.OrdinationResults` object, and you can call `.samples` on it to retrieve the transformed sample coordinates.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I thought it needed a distance matrix of the features and then transformed the samples.  Essentially, `PCA` but w/ distance metric instead of correlation/covariance. Thanks

Comment: No problem, happy to help!